# Here.com api, getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates for multiple coordinates

Tags: here-api

getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates: take only 1 value as parameter.
I've a long list of NMAGeoCoordinates and I'm looking for a way to get the "packageId" without doing multiple calls (or using a bounding box as parameter)

**UPDATE**

My iOS app has a list of routes (hundreds of them) and each route has multiple intermediate points.
For each route should be possible to download the map data offline. 
I'm using this api:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/maps-offline-maploader.html

I'm not using the other method based on NMAMapDataPrefetcher because I need to have control over packages installed.

So given a list of NMAGeoCoordinates I need to get a list of possible NMAMapPackage to download.

I can't use the start or destination coordinate because each route can include multiple countries.

I can't call getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates multiple times to get a complete list of possible countries included in a route (it's to many calls, on the order of tens for each route)

So I'm wondering if there a better way to solve this problem, maybe using a bounding box to get all the NMAMapPackage included in a route. 
I've also checked the REST api:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

looks like there a way to calculate a route and get a summary of country traversed, usign the RouteAttributeType "summaryByCountry". The response include a field "country" using an ISO 3166-1-alpha-3 format, but there no way to convert this value to an NMAMapPackage id.

Comment: Please provide the api and your implementation code details for us to help you better.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport more details provided

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Please provide your mobile ios and ide version you are using.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport XCode 10.1, iOS 12.1.2, latest here sdk (using cocoapods)

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way except you describe to receive NMAMapPackage using geoCoordinates.

This is the only way to use bounding box to download area he needs without multiple invocations.

```
@interface NMAGeoBoundingBox : NSObject<NSCoding>
+ (nullable instancetype)geoBoundingBoxContainingGeoCoordinates:(nonnull NSArray<NMAGeoCoordinates *> *)coordinates

@interface NMAMapDataPrefetcher : NSObject
- (NSInteger)fetchMapDataForBoundingBox:(nonnull NMAGeoBoundingBox *)boundingBox

                                  error:(NMAPrefetchRequestError *_Nullable)error

NS_SWIFT_NAME(fetchMapDataForBoundingBox(_:error:));
```

Comment: any news about this? Would be handy to get a list of NMAMapPackage give the route with a single api call!